# Firebase Dynamic Link can't find continueUserActivity when Localytics implemented

Tags: swift, swizzling, firebase-dynamic-links, localytics

While implementing Firebase Dynamic link on iOS, there is an error message in the debugging console when you click open dynamic link:

> FIRAnalytics/WARNING Implementation of application:continueUserActivity:restorationHandler: not found. Please add the handler into your App Delegate. Class: LLAppDelegateProxy

I create a minimized project to reproduce this issue. The new project only contains

```
Pod 'Localytics'
Pod 'Firebase/DynamicLinks’
```

And the only add code to `AppDelegate.swift`

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    FIRApp.configure()
    Localytics.autoIntegrate("apikey", launchOptions: launchOptions)

    return true
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any) -> Bool {
    let dynamicLink = FIRDynamicLinks.dynamicLinks()?.dynamicLink(fromCustomSchemeURL: url)
    if let dynamicLink = dynamicLink {
        print(dynamicLink.url)
        return true
    }

    return false
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity, restorationHandler: @escaping ([Any]?) -> Void) -> Bool {
    guard let dynamicLinks = FIRDynamicLinks.dynamicLinks() else {
        return false
    }
    let handled = dynamicLinks.handleUniversalLink(userActivity.webpageURL!) { (dynamiclink, error) in
        print(dynamiclink?.url)
    }

    return handled
}
```

It looks like Firebase tries to call `application:continueUserActivity:restorationHandler:` in Localytics' `LLAppDelegateProxy` instead of `AppDelegate.swift`. There is also a GitHub issue post from Branch.io: https://github.com/BranchMetrics/ios-branch-deep-linking/issues/485

The post states that there is a conflict between Google Analytics and Localytics and causes Branch not to be able to find the function `application:continueUserActivity:restorationHandler:` in the right place.

I follow their third suggestion to change the method swizzling:

```
//Their solution in Objc

SwizzleInstanceSelectorWithNewSelector(
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate class], 
    @selector(application:continueUserActivity:restorationHandler:),
    [self class], 
    @selector(BRapplication:continueUserActivity:restorationHandler:)
);

//My swift version in AppDelegate.swift

let originalSelector = #selector(AppDelegate.application(_:continueUserActivity:restorationHandler:))
let swizzledSelector = #selector(AppDelegate.firApplication(_:continueUserActivity:restorationHandler:))

let originalMethod = class_getClassMethod(AppDelegate.self, originalSelector)
let swizzledMethod = class_getClassMethod(AppDelegate.self, swizzledSelector)

method_exchangeImplementations(originalMethod, swizzledMethod)
```

However, this doesn't work for me. I'm still seeing the warning and link is still not handled.

Could you help me to fix the method swizzling or you have a better solution :]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the late answer about this issue.

We reached out to both Localytics and Firebase. Localytics offered us a solution which requires switching from auto-integration to manual integration. Although it is a bit annoying to use manual integration but it solves the issue :]

Answer (score 0):

After spending an almost full day, I have figure out the problem.

Below solution works like charm!

You can prevent Firebase from swizzling the methods in your AppDelegate by adding **`FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled`** set to **`NO`** in your app's **`info.plist`**

https://docs.localytics.com/dev/ios.html#integrating-with-firebase

Cheers